# QGIS actions with remote data

Tags: qgis, network, url, actions

I try to share several images through an action from QGIS. The images are in my PC and I need that other users can see them in their machines (we are in a local network). The images are geotagged in point layer:

[image]

In the atributes I created a field named PATH_1 with the next structure `\\<IP (PC where the photos are stored)>\<path>\<file.jpg>`

[image]

In properties > actions > new action > type: generic
In action text: `cmd/c [%PATH_1%]` I have seen this from other recomendations.

[image]

Finally when I try do run it,  it shows unable to run command:

[image]

How can I do this action? Is it possible?

Comment: Hi Oscar Soto, welcome to GIS SE. "I have seen this from other recomendations" - when asking questions, it would help to add a link where you've seen that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a syntax problem. You must enclose the path in double quotes: `"` and make sure to include a space after `cmd`. Thus the command to open a jpg file with an action looks like this:

```
cmd /c "[%PATH_1%]"
```

See [What Does “cmd /c” Means In Windows MS-DOS?](https://windowstect.com/what-does-cmd-c-means-in-windows-ms-dos/)